# Typescript handling error with one call

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I am new to typescript and I have two subscribe method nested. My question is there is way to handleError without invoking the method handleError two times ?

```
   this.service1.get(id).subscribe(val => {


        this.service2.get(id).subscribe(
          data => {
            ...
          },
          err => {
            this.handleError("Handle me service2", err);
          }
        );
      },
      err => {
        this.handleError("Handle me service1", err);
      }
    );
```

Thanks,

Comment: Even though you are invoking `handleError` at two places, but they will never be called together. Only one at a time will be called. There seems to be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator to "merge" observables and subscribe to resulting sequence:

```
this.service1.get(id).flatMap(val => {
    return this.service2.get(id);
}).subscribe(
    data => {
        //...
    },
    err => {
        this.handleError("Handle error", err);
    }
);
```